# Write-Write Conflict in In-Memory OLTP SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, in-memory-tables, in-memory-oltp

We have used the In Memory OLTP feature for our DB. When we are running transactions , we are encountering the below issue.

**SqlException:** *The current transaction attempted to update a record that has been updated since this transaction started. The transaction was aborted*

This issue arises due to write-write conflict and MS has recommended the RETRY logic in TRY CATCH. But that also doesn’t help us much as still the frequency of error is more.
If someone has any other possible solutions apart from RETRY logic, it will be of huge help.